# Use the screen area next to the notch

Tags: menu-bar, webcam

I am using a MacBook Pro 16' inch with the M1 processor and thus have the infamous black notch (housing the webcam) at the top of the screen.

I don't mind the notch at all and am not looking to hide it in any way.

What bothers me is all the screen real estate going to waste. I would like to prevent the annoying "window snap-back" effect that happens anytime you try to drag a window to the top area of the screen, as illustrated in the following attachement.

[image: illustration of issue]

As you see, anytime a window is placed near the notch (not under the notch, just in proximity) it refuses to remain in place. This effect happens when setting the menubar to automatically hide.

Is there anyway to make use of the all the pixels on the screen of a MacBook Pro?

Unfortunately on my screen recording, the notch is not pictured, and one can see a part of the desktop picture which is usually hidden.

After a long search online, I have only seen software or other stack overflow questions that seek to hide the notch and thus lose the screen real estate. I would like to be able to place windows under or behind the notch, as well as next to the notch.

Comment: Thank you xApple. I can't for the life of me understand why Apple developpers made this the default AND only behavior possible for the interface. You can make windows go out of the viewable area left, right, and bottom, but you cannot simply make the window sit on this precise part of the viewable area. Plus: if you can drag it there, you can obviously drag it back from there, it's not "stuck" in any way. This is all completely stupid. I guess apple developpers like to upset people, make them lose time; they must feel really powerful this way...

Comment: I am thinking: is anybody testing the latest prerelease versions of MacOS ? Has this bug been fixed for the next official release of MacOS ? Thank you.

Comment: I've tried but failed with an alternative, because just as you can't use the screen space, you can't hide just the left side. I use "hidden bar" app to curate a set of usable menu bar items, for example the "stats" open source app to showcase GPU/CPU usage etc. But this still leaves me with the app menu's to the left of the notch. Incredibly stupid.

Comment: I eventually bought a new macbook. Still no fix. This is probably the stupidest design choice i have seen from Apple. Why restrict windows placement at all ? They can always be accessed, wherever they are. Visibility is a user choice.

Comment: Still no fix or a workaround?

Comment: Good grief, this is ludicrous. Anyone have an update on this?

Comment: I found this (hack): https://notes.alinpanaitiu.com/Fullscreen%20apps%20above%20the%20MacBook%20notch